# How should I fix a small crack hole in Mirolin 3-piece tub/shower?

Tags: repair, bathtub

We've got an acrylic Mirolin tub/shower that recently developed a small pea-sized crack/hole in the bottom, causing water to gush out when the tub is filled. I just ordered a [repair kit from gelcoat.ca](http://www.gelcoat.ca/index.php?p=product&id=171&parent=122), but I have some doubts about how well it's going to work.

Does anyone have any experience with kits like this? Can I expect a reasonably long life from it, or am I looking at replacing the whole tub/shower because of this crack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where the crack/hole is, I would wonder about the support underneath the acrylic of the tub. Was the crack/hole caused by some part of the tub that was not supported getting flexed too much under regular use? If so, then I might doubt the repair kit myself. However, if the crack/hole was just due to some sharp object hitting the tub, then I suppose it will work fine. However, if it is a support issue, you might as well try the repair kit, because your other alternative is pulling the whole thing out to try to fix the lack of support, which sounds like a huge job. Just my $0.02 worth.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree completely, worth a try.  Cracked floors in a fairly new tub are almost always due to improper installation or support. Of course, there are some pretty cheap units out there also. If you end up replacing it, get a waffle bottom supported unit and lay it in a mortar bed from the beginning.

Comment: I can't really tell what the root problem was. The tub was installed by my home's previous owner, so I can't really tell if they did it properly or not. The crack looks like something might have dropped on it, but I don't really know. I'll give it a try and report back here with results.